# Wordpress Dropdown List Extension Recommedations

Tags: wordpress

i want to make a list of tire to repair kit in Wordpress. Customer selects size, profile and wheel, the result is type size, i mean the result is suitable to selected sizes. “type a, type b, type c, etc”

Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) extension, Custom Post Type UI does not match my purpose.

which extension do you recommend?